# Setting instance variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how do I assign a string to an instance variable so it is available to other methods in a class?

Comment: What do you mean by: *How can I make a string variable an instance variable so it is available to other methods in a class?*

Comment: I'd suggest you start from here: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/ if you really wanna learn Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

```
@variable = "your string"
```

As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it in the initialize method of your class and then it will be available to other methods in the class:

```
class MyClass

  def initialize
    @my_var = "hello"
  end

  def another_method
    puts @my_var
  end

end
```